# How to limit number of checkboxes that can be checked?

Tags: java, android

I have 4 checkboxes. I want user to select only two of them. How to set that limit?

Comment: Post your code..what have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily have an `int` variable that stores how many checkboxes are currently checked... Then any time `onCheckedChanged()` is called, you check that variable and if it would already be a third checkbox to be checked, you just set it to unchecked again...

Let's say you start with all the checkboxes unchecked. So you do:

```
int numberOfCheckboxesChecked = 0;
```

Then you set the `OnCheckChangedListener`:

```
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked && numberOfCheckboxesChecked >= 2) {
            checkbox1.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            // the checkbox either got unchecked
            // or there are less than 2 other checkboxes checked
            // change your counter accordingly
            if (isChecked) {
                numberOfCheckboxesChecked++;
            } else {
                numberOfCheckboxesChecked--;
            }

            // now everything is fine and you can do whatever
            // checking the checkbox should do here
        }
    }
});
```

(I have not tested the code, but it should work.)

Comment: Sure, if have some time, some code would be nice. In the meantime I will try to do what you said, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Please check the edit for some example code.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will test in a few minutes and let you now.

Comment: Note that I have made some edits to the code, the previous version wouldn't work.