# `listView` with `checkBox` that only allow 2 "checked" options, blocking the other ones

Tags: android, listview, multipleselection

I changed the code and made a custom `listView` with `single_row.xml`.
I got something working, but I thik my logic is messed up.
The goal is still the same, to only allow 2 "checks", and block the other possibilities once the 2 "checks" are `true`. But to also change the "checks" made.

e.g:
phase 1

- [X] - 1;
- [X] - 2;
- [ ] - 3 (blocked to click)

phase 2

- [X] - 1;
- [ ] - 2;
- [ ] - 3;

phase 3

- [X] - 1;
- [ ] - 2; (blocked to click)
- [X] - 3;

does this make any sense?

This is my code for the `checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){`

```
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            // if
                if (isChecked)
                    incr++;
                if (!isChecked)
                    incr--;
                if (incr > 2){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Somente 2 ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        
                        buttonView.setEnabled(false);
                }

            }
        });
```

---

#### Solved

saw the answer here: [How to limit number of checkboxes that can be checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220156/how-to-limit-number-of-checkboxes-that-can-be-checked)

and my code:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
```

@Override

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked && incr >= 2) {
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Somente 2 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    // the checkbox either got unchecked
                    // or there are less than 2 other checkboxes checked
                    // change your counter accordingly
                    if (isChecked) {
                        incr++;
                    } else {
                        incr--;
                    }

                    // now everything is fine and you can do whatever
                    // checking the checkbox should do here
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

create a integer var call it incr, and increament it for every selection (on listview listener), and if the value crosses more than two , then stop and Display message on toast, it will be easy and tricky method.

Comment: But I already have the int 'cont = listV.getCheckedItemCount();' for the checked items...or doesn't it work that way?

Comment: you need to increment the value of cont inside the onItemClick Listener and Check Condition before onItemClick Listener, and declare cont variable as Global variable.

Comment: hum...why increment `cont` on the `onItemClickListener()`? Can't it be on the `onItemClick` like I did? 
And check condition? How do I do that? 
Thank you, and sorry for all your trouble :/

Comment: No, you misunderstand it,I said to increment value inside onItemClick() listener, and check the condition if(count>2), before this listener to perform what you desired.

Comment: I have the `cont = listV.getCheckedItemCount()` that returns the number of items selected. I need the one 'int incr' like you said to see if that number is >2 right? 
But I dont understand how to 'block' it before the listener :/

Comment: ? Sorry again. But I still can't make it work. How and why should I make the condition before the listening? I can't quite understand it...sorry once again

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact answer but may help you.
xml file
 `<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/types">
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/take_out"
        android:text="Take-Out"
        android:checked="true"
      />
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/sit_down"
        android:text="Sit-Down"
      />
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/delivery"
        android:text="Delivery"
      />
    </RadioGroup>`

java file

```
RadioGroup types=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.types);

  switch (types.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.sit_down:
      r.setType("sit_down");
      break;

    case R.id.take_out:
      r.setType("take_out");
      break;

    case R.id.delivery:
      r.setType("delivery");
      break;`
```

and [follow this official site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html).

Comment: thank you for your response! I will try it and post news :)

Comment: hey! Sorry for the late response, but got caught up on other things. I changed my code (will update now) and created a custom `listview` to have checkboxes. I dont use neither `radioButtons` nor multiple choice. Any ideas?

Comment: just edited it...any ideas?